# Using a 10K ohm thermistor as a 5K

Tags: resistors, sensor, thermistor

I have a water cooler that is using a B3950 10K sensor.

For energy saving reasons, the microcontroller is limited to 6 degrees celsius (R=24k for the 10k ohm)

I can't modify the microcontroller or how it works however I want to manipulate the reading sent to the micro controller to achieve lower temperatures.

Typically I want the real R=28k (3 degree celsius) to be read by the micro controller as 24k (6 degree celsius)

Is this possible and how can it be achieved?

Another thing I thought of is using additional resistors to make the 10K ohm act as a 5K ohm and map the temperatures as per the B3950 data sheets?

Please share your thoughts

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems like you have more than one question. You can definitely make the 28k look like 24k, just by putting a resistor in parallel with the NTC thermistor. This will also throw off temperature readings at the high end of the scale. I don't know if that is a problem for you.

Comment: @mkeith what kind of resistor and how to calculate it please?

Comment: Controller read the voltage, not the resistance. Thermistor works as one shoulder of voltage divided. If you change thermistor value, the another resistor's value should be changed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Typically I want the real R=28k (3 degree celsius) to be read by the micro controller as 24k (6 degree celsius)

This part is pretty easy. The resistance of two resistors in parallel is as follows:

- R<sub>PARALLEL</sub> = 1 / (1 / R<sub>1</sub> + 1 / R<sub>2</sub>)

So you want to solve this:

- 24k = 1 / (1/28k + 1/R)
- 24000 * (1/28000 + 1/R) = 1
- 0.8571 + 24000/R = 1
- 1 - 0.8571 = 24000/R
- R = 24000 / (1 - 0.8571)
- R = 168 k

But 168 k is not a standard value so you might have to use 169 k.
28 k in parallel with 169 k is 24.02 k. So the error is much smaller than the "slop" in the resistor values. Should be fine.

Note: this will make the controller think that the temperature is 6 C when the real temperature is 3 C, but it will also cause temperature errors all across the temperature range. It is up to you to make sure this does not create a problem. I don't know how the system works or what the temperature information is used for. So don't blame me if something goes wrong. ;-)